# F# non-static methods in modules

Tags: f#

I am an absolute newbie to coding, but I need to modify a F# script. It always gives me the error "Method or object constructor 'x' is not static". I read that this might be due to the fact that I try to call a non-static method within a module, which is by default static. For example 'x' = Get.Axis():

```
module Primitives =
let axis1 = Zaber.Motion.Ascii.Device.GetAxis(1)
```

The manual only provides code in C#: `var axis1 = device.GetAxis(1);`
If I use `static member` instead of `let`, I'll get a 'unexpected keyword static in definition' error, although I checked the indentation as suggested in another question.

Comment: Your problem description is a bit inconsistent. Your error message suggests the method you're trying to call is declared static, but the example you provide from the manual looks like a non-static call.

Comment: To put it another way, a method cannot be "static by default." It's either static or it isn't.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using the [Zaber Motion Library](https://www.zaber.com/software/docs/motion-library/ascii/references/csharp/#device_2), I think what you need to do is get an *instance* of a device first, instead of trying to access the class in a static context.

Their documentation includes an example of [how to get a list of devices by opening a serial port](https://www.zaber.com/software/docs/motion-library/ascii/tutorials/open_port/):

```ml
open Zaber.Motion.Ascii

use connection = Connection.OpenSerialPort("COM3")
let deviceList = connection.DetectDevices()

match deviceList |> Seq.tryHead with // See if we got at least one device
| Some device ->
    let axis = device.GetAxis(1)
    // TODO: Do whatever you want with the axis here
| None ->
    failwith "No Devices Found on COM3"
```